# How to align 2 QPushButtons inside a QLineEdit generically

Tags: qt

I have a custom widget which has a QLineEdit & 2 QPushButtons inside it.
I want to align them generically so that they look the same on all platforms(WIN, LINUX & osX).

I tried to align them using offsets by manually checking different offsets. It worked fine for windows&linux but on mac, the buttons are hidden by the QLineEdit.

I am wondering if there's a generic way in which i can have these buttons inside QLineEdit which works for all platforms & scaling values.

Comment: You should provide a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: QLineEdit with two buttons sounds like a [`QSpinBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html). Maybe you could start with that one if the layout is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

[search field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et9se.png)

As the image shows, i want to have two buttons just like the one in visual studio. I tried QComboBox but it din't solve the purpose as it's label is not editable.

I solved this on windows by moving the two buttons by their sizes,

```
adjFirstBtnWidth = lineEditWidth - firstButtonWidth - secondButtonWidth

adjSecondBtnWidth = lineEditWidth - secondButtonWidth
```

Now, I moved the first button by `adjFirstBtnWidth` & second button by `adjSecondBtnWidth` on x axis.

It seems to work on windows & Linux but I've to wait to see if it's working on OSX or not.

Hope this is helpful to someone.